# CKEditor image restriction

Tags: laravel, image, ckeditor

when user login and try to add image using CKEditor other user images also display there from server.
how to make this according to user when user A login User B image will not be able to view.

Comment: Are you managing any database or not ?

Comment: Yes this will store like this in database 

<p>This is text&nbsp;<img alt="" src="/designthroubs/storage/app/media/images/1534047133.jpg" style="height:600px; width:2000px" /></p>